# jenkins gerrit trigger different jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

i am looking if there is a way when the developer commit and push to gerrit (with custom comments), it will trigger certain jobs

example

git commit -m "DO_BUILD DO_TEST some_commit_comments", so when it is pushed to gerrit, it will launch jenkins jobs DO_ BUILD and jobs DO TEST

or

git commit -m "DO_BUILD some_commit_comments", so when it is pushed to gerrit, it will launch jenkins jobs DO_ BUILD and jobs DO TEST

i am sorry if this has been asked somewhere, but so far i cant find it anywhere

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think [Gerrit TOPIC](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#topics) can be used for this. Because there is a build parameter in [Gerrit Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) based on TOPIC. So in DO_ BUILD case the topic would be DO_ BUILD which will trigger the *build* job, and DO_BUILD_TEST would trigger *test* job which has a *build* job dependency. in this way you dont need to spam your commit message with build instructions

Comment: i tried creating 2 different jenkins job, but with different TOPIC, both of them got executed even though when i commit the code to gerrit with only 1 TOPIC.  Any idea how should i fix it ? thanks